# How to scale a javascript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working on an npm package and I was wondering how do I divide the content of a big class on typescript.

Using vanilla js, I can do something like this:

```
class MyBigClass {
  // content
}

MyBigClass.prototype.initDatabase = require('./init-database');
MyBigClass.prototype.start = require('./start');
MyBigClass.prototype.stop = require('./stop');
```

So, a "big" class could be divided into small pieces of code.

What is the best practice to do something similar on typescript?

And how can I still use the `private/public/protected` modifiers?

Answer (score 2):

You should not try to break down a big class because it is big.

You should look at the design of your class and identify why the class is big.

Does it take on multiple responsibilities?
Should it be refactored to multiple smaller classes?

Consider following some design principles such as SOLID.

Breaking a big class into multiple files for the sake of it makes it harder to maintain, not easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your example above incorrectly refers to "require" being vanilla JS, this statement is incorrect.

What I think you are searching for is the [Import/Export of Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html); Which is a "vanilla JS" concept introduced with [ECMAScript2015](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html).

```
import { initDatabase } from './init-database';
import { start} from './start';
import { stop } from './stop';

class MyBigClass {
  private initDatabase(arg1: string, arg2: number) {initDatabase(arg1, arg2)}
  start() {start()}
  protected stop () {stop ()}
}

class MyClassThatNowLooksLittleButHasBigFeatures extends MyBigClass {

}
```

Comment: `require` is very common, see https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/ , there's nothing wrong with it. `import` and `export` are other options (and your answer doesn't explain how to do it with Typescript and `private/public/protected`, which is what the question was asking)

Comment: Require is not vanilla JS and it certainly is not  part of typescript. I guess I beat you to the edit. Usually when answering a question I get an answer out first and then revise.

Comment: I don't know what your first answer looked like, but people vote on what they read and don't usually check back periodically to update their vote. If you choose to answer first and only turn it into a good answer afterwards, you shouldn't be surprised about downvotes.